# Convert very large value into FLOAT in python

Tags: python

Im stuck on how to write a function which get as an input ether

- large string
- large integer

and transform into a float.

The problem is when I transform into a FLOAT, it is missing characters.

```
#value= int(45264444.4444444444466666254188888888888526)
value= "45264444.4444444444466666254188888888888526"

float(value)

output:45264444.44444445
```

Comment: If you actually need that much precision, floats are not the right tool for the job. You likely don't actually need that much precision, though.

Comment: use decimal instead of float and maybe set precison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `float` can not store arbitrary numbers, its precision is limited.
A `float` will store the few most significant digits of a number (in binary form), and discard the rest.
That is why you see the value truncated.

For a more in-depth look at the problem, see for example https://0.30000000000000004.com/, or some general guide on floating-point arithmetic.